# Registration of Azure Resource Provider hangs indefinitely

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-service

I'm just starting to look into Azure and AKS. In order to do this, I have to enable a bunch of resource providers. I did this using the Azure CLI, like so:

```
az provider register -n Microsoft.Network                                               
az provider register -n Microsoft.Storage
az provider register -n Microsoft.Compute
az provider register -n Microsoft.ContainerService
```

But, for some reason, one of those providers, specifically `Microsoft.Compute`, is indefinitely in a `Registering` state. I can check it via CLI, like so:

```
$ az provider show -n Microsoft.Compute |jq .registrationState          
"Registering"
```

Or via the portal, which yields the same result:
[image: Azure Portal Screenshot]

I left it in this state overnight and it's still in the same state. I tried unregistering, which left it hanging in the `Unregistering` state. Then tried to register again and it has been like that for about 10 minutes. The other 3 providers registered almost instantaneously.

Comment: Same here. How did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue that pops up on occasion. As far as I can tell there's no self-service way to fix this when it happens, and your only recourse is to file a support request via the Azure Portal here: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview